# Typescript says my object is missing properties that it isn't missing

Tags: typescript, module

I'm working on a project that has the following pattern:

```js
interface IAuthProvider {
  middleware: () => void
  getInput: () => void
}

class Password implements IAuthProvider {
  middleware = () => {}
  getInput = () => {}
}

class Email implements IAuthProvider {
  middleware = () => {}
  getInput = () => {}
}

const providerNames = ['Email', 'Password']

type AuthProviderNamespace = { [K in typeof providerNames[number]]: IAuthProvider }

// error: Type 'typeof Password' is missing the following properties from type 'IAuthProvider': middleware, getInput
const providers: AuthProviderNamespace = { Email, Password }
```

I need to use `AuthProviderNamespace` because this kind of object will be imported in a module and passed directly to a function that will iterate over it:

```js
import * as AuthProviders from './providers/index.ts'

const providers = instantiateProviders(AuthProviders)
```

And so I need to type `AuthProviders`. But I'm doing something wrong such that typescript doesn't recognize Email and Password as implementers of IAuthProvider. Can I fix this?

Playground: https://tsplay.dev/wQV7jN

Comment: But `Password` and `Email` are class constructors that *do not* have the required properties; only *instances* of those classes created like `new Password()` or `new Email()` have those properties.  The compiler is giving you a correct error here.  Do you want `AuthenticationProviderNamespace` to hold *constructors* for `IAuthenticationProvider`s, or `IAuthenticationProvider` themselves?  What are you going to do with `providers`?  [See this code](https://tsplay.dev/N5epdN).

Comment: @jcalz it should hold the constructors. How can I type that then? I tried creating a type `type Constructor = (args: string) => IAuthenticationProvider` and then changing the namespace to `type AuthProviderNamespace = { [K in typeof providerNames[number]]: ProviderConstructor }` but that didn't work either https://tsplay.dev/NDkvjw

Comment: I already showed you [here](https://tsplay.dev/m0y6DW)... you need a [construct signature](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#construct-signatures) like `new () => IAuthenticationProvider`.  Of course that means zero-arg constructors.  Is that what you want?  What are you going to do with `providers`?  Show some example code please... is it `x instanceof providers.Email` or is it `x = new providers.Email` or something else?

Comment: @jcalz ah beautiful, that did it. Sorry I didn't see your link the first time. Yeah I'll be passing this object to a factory that will actually instantiate the classes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is correct.  The value `{Email: Email, Password: Password}` is an object whose properties are each *constructors* of `IAuthProvider` objects.  But the type `{Email: IAuthProvider, Password: IAuthProvider}` corresponds to an object whose `Email` and `Password` properties are `IAuthProvider` *instances*, not constructors of such instances.  The class constructor `Email` does not have a `getInput` property, so it cannot be an `IAuthProvider`:

```
Email.getInput; // <-- error, Property 'getInput' does not exist on type 'typeof Email'
```

Assuming your intent with `providers` is to use its properties to construct new instances of `IAuthProvider`, like this:

```
const provider = new providers.Email(); // note, assuming a no-arg constructor
provider.getInput(); // okay
provider.middleware(); // okay
```

Then you need to change the `AuthProviderNamespace` type so that its properties are no-arg constructors of `IAuthProvider` instances.  You can use a [construct signature](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#construct-signatures) like `{ new(): IAuthProvider }` or like `new () => IAuthProvider`:

```
type AuthProviderNamespace = {
  [K in typeof providerNames[number]]: new () => IAuthProvider
}
```

And then everything works as desired:

```
const providers: AuthProviderNamespace = { Email, Password }
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgJIEECuYAWAFKAewDdgATaZAbwFgAoZZAW3LIBsIB3OKCALmQAKAJTIAvAD5kxQuXqMA5hDCoQAB2wCR4qTLl0AvvXoI2cAM7nkeC+c6EoZZMCZqOTCOCsZs+IqQooanlmVg5uXnEhUUlqZCMGZCUVdWwo7ViqePoEkzNLZABRJjhgNmdXd08wbyxcAhJySlpEljJ2Lh4UMWidOITFZVUNMHSYqSyE3LoEQhBzUbV-JqgAOTgPKx6AbQByYtK2XYAaZF2bS3tHXYBdYzoDsoA6ZOHsAG5kAHov5AAeAC0AOQ0CIUFODTU0DAAE8zq9UmBdsgyIQIFYQIRRhAAB7ABbIObIWFQs4kiCEGBFEplXb3cnIOp+RqBdabNSIbrBRLbADSzhAxJhUMpyCWLOgbPR2xAmCYACNoDcbgIQFxerEfPVloEcvdZvNFjroOYBEyGgFJRt0RykFEso82BDbFcnNMDQTxZagj01ZwxcaoOYno6RO96F6Vi8hoiw99foQANZwGERwNPNodCIQOM-QnJmFAA)